# Block specific file types from google search

Tags: block, robots.txt

I want to block XML files from Google bot except sitemap.XML. I am using Lazyest Gallery for my WordPress image gallery. Every gallery folder have a XML file containing the details of images. The problem is, now Google index those XML files instead of galleries. My site search also showing XML files instead of albums.
will

```
Disallow: /*/*.xml$
```

work?

I have excluded feeds by adding

```
Disallow: /*/rss/$
```

to my robots.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To block all files of a certain type the simplest way is:

```
Disallow: /*.xml$
Disallow: /*.XML$
```

Robots.txt is case sensitive, thus the two entries (you can leave 1 out if you know they are all one case). Now to make sure we aren't blocking the sitemap.xml we need to allow it first:

```
Allow: /sitemap.xml
Disallow: /*.xml$
Disallow: /*.XML$
```

There is also a sitemap directive in robots.txt to reference the location of the sitemap, so we can add that too:

```
Allow: /sitemap.xml
Disallow: /*.xml$
Disallow: /*.XML$

Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Comment: thanks, I think it worked, waiting for next update from Google bot